# How to effectively gather ETH across multiple accounts?

Tags: addresses, accounts

I have a online payments service which allows clients to pay with ETH. For each client paying, I generate a new ETH deposit address. When the funds arrive, I can then mark the clients invoice as paid, and grab the relevant ETH.

However, withdrawing from ETH isnt cheap. So if the client only paid 10 USD, I lose a lot when I send that ETH out to my own wallet.

So how does one get around this?

1. Bitcoin allows you to generate multiple addresses that link back to the same private key. I don't think ETH can do that, can it?
2. Should I perhaps set the gas fees as low as possible in the hopes of just keeping that transaction fee down?
3. Any other ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using other cheaper chains like Polygon or Binance Smart Chain? That can probably keep your gas fees pretty low.

Also, I'm curious as to why do you create a new blockchain address for every new client.